# How to get the prior data which is changed using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the prior symbol which is not similar to the current one.

Example: if table A holds the historical data, then how can I achieve the table B with having prior symbol which is different?

[image]

Comment: Why "A+" and not "B"?

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.symbol as prev_symbol
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.type = t.type and t2.symbol <> t.symbol and t2.date < date
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2;
```

Note that your particular example has ties for the previous date with a given symbol.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no way to choose between the two symbols on the same day.

You need a way to resolve the ambiguity -- a time component on `date` or another column that specifies a *stable* ordering (one with no ties).

Answer (score 1):

Given your data this query will get you what you need, but since you do not have a unique identifier in your rows you have duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA(xType varchar(5), Symbol varchar(5), xDate date)
INSERT INTO #TableA
VALUES ('LT','A','6/24/13'),
    ('LT','A','6/23/13'),
    ('LT','A','6/22/13'),
    ('LT','A+','6/21/13'),
    ('LT','B','6/21/13');


DECLARE @dt DATE

SET @dt = '6/24/13'

select t1.xType,t1.Symbol CurrentSymbol,t3.Symbol PriorSymbol, t1.xDate CurrentDate 
from #TableA t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT MAX(xDate) xDate, Symbol from #TableA t2 where t2.xDate < t1.xDate and t1.Symbol <> t2.Symbol GROUP BY Symbol) t3
where t1.xDate = @dt
```

You can check the result in this [**SQL Fiddle link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04f83/2/0)